# Muzei plugin getting stuck in state where it will never get an onUpdate() call

Tags: java, android, retrofit, muzei

I've written a Muzei plugin that uses the Flickr API to check for and fetch a remote image once an hour. I've noticed that sometimes my app will get in to a bad state however and will stop updating. I've checked the shared prefs (where Muzei stores the next update time) and I've noticed that the `scheduled_update_time_millis` variable is no longer present in my art source xml file.

I've double checked my `RemoteMuzeiArtSource.onTryUpdate()` method call and I've verified that it should always either call

```
long CHECK_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000L; // 1 hr
scheduleUpdate(System.currentTimeMillis() + CHECK_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
```

or throw a `RetryException`

I'm unable to consistently repro getting into this bad state unfortunately, so I'm not sure how it happens.

Full source for my RemoteMuzeiArtSource class lives here: [CactusArtSource](https://github.com/andrewflynn/CactusOfTheDay/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/aflynn/cactusoftheday/CactusArtSource.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: turns out that any `RuntimeException` thrown during execution of `onTryUpdate` or `onUpdate` will result unsurprisingly in not getting through the entire method and thus (in my case) not scheduling a new update. In my case, it was a RetrofitError being thrown during a bad network event. I threw a little [try-catch handling](https://github.com/andrewflynn/CactusOfTheDay/commit/c950acfd14f6de30769469a7c30fa7f65e06308d) at it and seems to have fixed the error